# Optimize Custom Parameters in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to create some custom parameters to optimize and came across this helpful link [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/defining-weights-of-a-custom-layer-as-parameters/17687). However, I'm a bit confused as to why this code works.

Here is the code with some slight modifications from the original post to clearly see the behavior of the optimization.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np

class Mask(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Mask, self).__init__()
        self.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(data=torch.Tensor(5, 5), requires_grad=True)

        self.weight.data.uniform_(-1, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        masked_wt = self.weight.mul(1)
        return masked_wt


class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.mask = Mask()

    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.mask(x)
        return x

model = Model()
indata = torch.ones(5,5)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.001)

while True:
    x = model(indata)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = F.l1_loss(indata,x)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    print(model.mask.weight)
```

So two questions:

1. In the forward function of the Mask class, why do I need to do self.weight.mul(1) and why doesn't x get used?
2. x = model(indata) clearly does per element multiplication between the 5x5 matrix indata and the weight, but how does this happen if we didn't use x in the forward function of Mask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, `Mask.forward` discard `x` completely. However, the output of your model "sees" `indata` when computing the loss.
What you are actually teaching your model is to have `mask.weight == indata`.

Comment: It seems you are right. If I set `indata` randomly `mask.weight` eventually equals `indata`. However my intention was to update `mask.weight` to equal all ones. Changing `weight.mul(1)` to `weight.mul(x)` fixed this behavior